# There is an `Object.values()` on typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to iterate all values from an Object that I'll use to filter another array.

Searching on Google I found `Object.values()`, but it doesn't work on typescript.

There is something equivalent that I can use on typescript?

Comment: `Object.values` maybe coming soon

Comment: Post your code and will try to solve it with other methods.

Comment: TypeScript just compiles to JavaScript. So if there's a function in JavaScript, it'll work in TypeScript; you might need to do some work to get TypeScript to recognize it, but you can use it. The real question is, will it work in the browsers you need to support: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.values

Comment: You can just do something like this (<any>Object).values()

Comment: Stop posting `any` hacks when there is a straightforward way to do it correctly

Comment: @Kinduser I've already got an alternative method, really thanks. I just want a better code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typescript ES5 and ES6 does not have this method, because of this we need this workaround to use the JS method:

```
(<any>Object).values(yourObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your target to ES2017 (by writing `--target ES2017` or setting `"target": "es2017"` in your tsconfig file) to let TypeScript know you're running on an ES2017 runtime and thus have access to ES2017 APIs like `Object.values`

Comment: Why the target should be set to `es2017`? This is client-side app. That most likely has `es5` target.

Comment: Well if you want to use `Object.values` you need to be on an ES2017 runtime.

Comment: I got this `Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher`

Comment: No, you don't. This is polyfillable feature that can be used in ES5.